# Where is the best place in a checkout flow to ask users to save the payment method?

Tags: e-commerce, checkout

In a checkout process, I need to show an option for the user to save their payment method info, to pay faster next time. Only registered users can save this info, so if a user wants to save they either have to sign in or create an account. The checkout form is a single form, no steps.

Two options come to mind:

1. After the user enters payment info, before sending to payment. This will trigger a modal window to sign in or register.
2. After payment is processed, on the success screen.

There are pros and cons to either of these, but i'm curious to hear what you think.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take as an example the Steam platform (where you can buy games).

When you take something (like the last game you want) and proceed to checkout, steam ask you your payment info. At the bottom of it, there's a little box checked by default with the text "Keep my payment info for next time".

In psychology, we call it "Default" (from [MINDSPACE](https://kittysjones.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/mindspace.jpg) model for behavioral change). People tends to accept the default option.

So, to answer directly, do as steam does : During the payment info, let them uncheck this little box (or something similar, as you wish, as long as your users understand) if they don't want. So that you'll have more people with default payment infos than if you did the other way around, making it easier for your users to pay (and so, winning you more money in the end).

Of course, you have to let them change it as much as they want (I mean, in the process, if they enter something different than their previous payment info, ask them if they want to change their default payment infos or if it's another payment info that they could register => It depends on your business).

Comment: i tend to agree, but i can't have the checkbox checked because i have a condition - i can save payment info only for registered users. so if user is NOT logged in, i'll have to show the checkbox as disabled until they register (if at all).

Comment: Is it possible to ask them to log in after the payout? Like "Oh you paid this, with those info, want to create a new account to keep those infos?"

Comment: @Martin, don’t show the checkbox for people who are not registered. Or add a link like “To save the payment method, please log in or create an account”. It would otherwise be confusing, not knowing why the checkbox is disabled.

Comment: @Rhevan i think that's a good direction, only concern is that maybe after the payout i lose the user's attention and they might just close the confirmation screen. but i guess this is something to A/B test...

Comment: @Martin Yes, A/B testing is the best way to see if your user attention is lost after this step. But maybe check how Amazon does it for new accounts?

Comment: @Rhevan Amazon doesn't allow checkout as guest. eBay does, but i couldn't find online how an updated confirmation page looks like. I believe they don't give this option.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to put that at the end of the payment process.

- For a new user, or for a user that has not saved the payment template, they know that the payment info that they input is correct and the payment success, then they can decide to save that payment info for later use next time or not.
- For the old user who did save the payment info, if they would like to change any payment info, they can change and get feedback about their payment process (is it successful or not,....) before choosing to save or not save that change for next payment.